# Affecting other component when router-link is active

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to build a sidebar with 3 types of columns.
The first column contains the main options
after selecting one of the main option a new navigation with sub-options is 
opened.
the third column contain filters and not part of my question.

Every column is a different vue file with different css configurations.
I'm trying to make a right-border on the sub option sidebar, when the router-link of the main nav is clicked.

I tried to make it happen with CSS with the :active psuedo class but with no success affecting other class (trying to affect div in another vue page when router-link is active)
I thought maybe it will be easier with vue but I have no idea how to start because I'm new to vue and still learning how to use it properly.

Just to be clear: When the link in MainNav.vue is active I want to apply css on a DIV in SecondNav.vue.

Example

```
a {

  &.active ~ .SecondClass {
            color: var(blue);
            fill: blue;
            position: relative;
            border-right: 3px solid var(blue);
}
```

Comment: First you have a small mistake. It should be `&:active`, not `&.`. Second `:active` styles don't remain after the click, only for the period of the mouse click.

Comment: I think you should add a class to the div with the desired styles when the link is clicked.